# I want to deploy Java code in already-built static website. What's the most effective way to do this?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, web

I have a Java program that currently runs in my IDE that I want to put on my website. I want to put this code online so that anyone can easily use it. I need to figure out how to host the Java code, as well as how to have it communicate with the frontend of my website. I'd like the results of my Java code to be accessible to anyone at any time through my website.

I've taught myself a bit of Java Spring in the past weeks, but still haven't quite put the pieces together. How am I supposed to do this?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: What kind os program? A desktop app? A web app? Please, provide more details.

Comment: To run Java on the server the site host has to support Java. A Spring-based web app is a different beast than a static site—you’ll need to be more clear regarding your exact goals and what your Java app actually is.

Comment: You have to ask/switch your host... But it's only "a few clicks" at the big/specialized providers ...and you could "interact" with your "static site"...

Comment: The program is plain Java code that can be run in an IDE. I'd like to make this code usable in a webapp.

When you say that I need to switch my host, I don't quite follow. Which host would I need to use, and how would I need to deploy it to make it work?

Comment: You can't just run a console Java program on a website.  Java code has to be written specifically to work in a web environment.  Take a look at [Java Spring](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-tutorial) to see one of the frameworks for web development.

Comment: I'm aware of what Spring is and that I need to build a frontend for it to communicate with, etc. I just don't understand how to actually use the tools provided to do this. That was all stated in the OP.

I want to be able to press a button on my website, have that execute the Java code, and return the result to a textarea on the front end.